# Json4s producing weird Json

Tags: json, scala, scalatra, json4s

This is what I have:

```
(("foo" ->
  ("bar" -> 5) ~
  ("bar2" -> 5)) ~
 ("something" -> "else"))
```

This is what I get:

```
[
  {
   "foo": {
      "bar": 5,
      "bar2": "5"
   },
   "something": "else",
  }
]
```

But this is what I'd like to get back:

```
{
   "foo": {
      "bar": 5,
      "bar2": "5"
    },
    "something": "else",
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

detail

```
def getAll: JValue = db withSession { implicit db: Session =>
    // getUsersQuery fetchs all users
    getUsersQuery.list.map { u =>

       ("foo" ->
       ("bar" -> 5) ~
       ("bar2" -> 5)) ~
       ("something" -> "else")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a error in your question:

> This is what I have:

Actually you have not a single `JObject`, but a collection of `JObject`:

```
val jObject = (
  ("foo" ->
    ("bar" -> 5) ~
    ("bar2" -> 5)) ~
  ("something" -> "else")
)

val collection: JValue = List(jObject)
```

And collection of `JObject` will be converted to json array (since it could be `List()` or `List(jObject, jObject)`).

If you want to get a single value you have to extract this value from collection somehow:

```
// note type inference here, it will be Seq[JObject] or similar
def getAll = db withSession { implicit db: Session =>
    // getUsersQuery fetchs all users
    getUsersQuery.list.map { u =>

       ("foo" ->
       ("bar" -> 5) ~
       ("bar2" -> 5)) ~
       ("something" -> "else")

    }
}

for {
  j <- getAll.headOption
} println(pretty(render(j)))
```

For single value (like in your initial question) it works just fine:

```
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
// or
// import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

val source = (
  ("foo" ->
    ("bar" -> 5) ~
    ("bar2" -> 5)) ~
  ("something" -> "else")
)

pretty(render(source))
// String =
// {
//   "foo" : {
//     "bar" : 5,
//     "bar2" : 5
//   },
//   "something" : "else"
// }
```

**Update** (response to comment):

```
def getAll: JValue = (1 to 2).toList map { u =>
  ("bar" -> 5) ~
  ("bar2" -> 5)
}

val result = (
  ("foos" -> getAll) ~
  ("something" -> "else")
)

pretty(render(result))
// String =
// {
//   "foos":[{
//     "bar":5,
//     "bar2":5
//   },{
//     "bar":5,
//     "bar2":5
//   }],
//   "something":"else"
// }
```

Comment: I don't want a single value but would still like to keep my collection but without the `[]`. At the end of the collection, I'd like to display the `"something" : "else"` part. Would this be possible?